# Date format advice

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate

When emailing a PDF from my app, im using the following to get the file title

`NSString *date = [[NSDate date] description];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@.pdf", self.certificate.certificateType.title, date];`

It gives me a filename of:

`myfilename.pdf 2012-11-25 21:35:45 + 0000`

Is there way I can get rid of the `+0000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually want to aviod using spaces in your filenames.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss";
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.pdf", self.certificate.certificateType.title, dateString];
```

Comment: You want HH (24 hour), not hh (12 hour) for the hour.

Comment: And you need mm, not MM for minutes (MM is month).

Answer (score 1):

The `description` method should never be used for anything except debugging. Its implementation could change anytime (and for `NSDate`, it has changed in the past).

The much better solution is to use an `NSDateFormatter` with a specific date format to ensure a consistent result.

The answer by @Eugene gives a good example.